# About request priority in chrome timeline

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the event log of chrome timeline panel,we usually see the priority field of every request send.I find some post mention this,i.e. [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc/edit)
and [chrome developers doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/critical-request-chains)
,but I thinks it's little old or enough detailed.

So,is there latest doc?Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll have to examine [ResourceScheduler-related](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=ResourceScheduler+-status%3AUnconfirmed+-status%3AWontFix+-status%3AAvailable+-status%3ADuplicate+component%3AInternals+&sort=-modified) stuff on   the bugtracker and in the source code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your reply.I see the link but it's too large and not friendly to read.Is there any good post about "ResourceScheduler-related" or I should read something of HTTP or TCP/IP first?

Comment: Is not clear what exactly you want to know.

Comment: In the doc:Queueing. The browser queues requests when:
There are higher priority requests.
There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.

Comment: What I want to know is more details about the "higher priority requests".

Comment: @wOxxOm You can see the red region of  [the pic](http://www.blog.ne-smalltown.com/commonUpload/2017-01-24_22-15-29.jpg),that's what I say.